# Max memory available per ASP.NET worker process on IIS6

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-6

I am running IIS6 on Windows 2003 Server 32 bit. I have read that IIS6 has a maximum virtual memory limit of 2gb (3gb with the 3gb switch fipped).

What I am unclear on is whether this means all ASP.NET sessions have 2gb between them or 2gb each.

So if I have a session variable storing 200kb and have 10,000 active sessions am I going to be hitting up against this 2gb limit?

Answer (score 0):

In general the advice is to leave these options unticked for ASP.NET applications, it affects how quickly the appPool recycles more information [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1268ed60-cb2f-489b-865c-a68d6acc05af/difference-between-maximum-virtual-memory-maximum-memory-in-used-in-iis-6-?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) summary below:

Physical and Virtual memory: This section is for recycling application pools which consume too much memory.  Focusing on physical I typically like to limit app pools around 800MB to 1200 MB max on a 32 bit app with very few app pools depending on the number and amount of memory.  On a server with 2 GB RAM I'd set it at around 800MB max.  On a 4GB of RAM server around 1GB and more if more with a max around 1200.  On a 64 bit web front end with 8-16 GB memory I've heard of settings of 2GB of RAM or even allowing it to let it ride, rather than limiting it.

You really need to profile it since these can really grow to process and cache.  The greater the amount of memory and the greater the load the higher the worker process will grow.  When people ask about configuring the app pool, this is where they are usually asking what the numbers should be.  What you are doing here is explicitly limiting the app pool from consuming more memory.

Notice this setting is on the recycle tab, there's a reason for that.  When an app pool reaches the max it isn't like the max processor setting.  It will cycle the worker process which is like a tiny reboot or similar to an iisreset, but not since sometimes we want this to happen so we can release our memory.  You really don't want to cycle more than a couple of times per 24 hour period in an ideal world.  I've heard of some trying to cycle right before the morning peak occurs so they have the most amount of memory available, then a cycle right at the end of the day before the backups or crawling begins.

Basically the recommendation is not setting a limit (leave the options unchecked) because once the limit is hit IIS will recycle the application pool causing all active users to be temporarily disconnected from the site. You users will likely receive an HTTP 500 while the application pool recycles and then once it's back there will be a delay while the application pool warms up.

**Sessions**

For an application of any size do not use InProc (stored in memory) sessions use state server or SQL server to store your sessions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

**Conclusion**

It really depends on the profile of your application, if your expecting  10,000 active sessions though don't use InProc, don't use IIS6  and don't use a 32 bit server.